# Error while loading route with Fixture data in emberjs

Tags: jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I actually followed [exact procedure to produce ToDOMVC](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/planning-the-application/) to make this one, but I can not figure out in the world why I get errors below:

> Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array.
>
> You passed (generated questions controller) ember.js:394 Uncaught
> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addArrayObserver'

below is the code

index.html

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="questions"><!--ACW-not sure should be question or equizz-->
                <ul id="question-list" >
                    {{#each}}
                        <li>
                            <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>{{desc}}</p>
                        </li>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
</script><!--template END-->
```

application.js

```
window.Equizz = Ember.Application.create();
Equizz.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
```

router.js

```
Equizz.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('questions', { path: '/' });
});

Equizz.EquizzRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return this.store.find('question');
  }
});
```

question.js

```
Equizz.Question = DS.Model.extend({
    qid: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string'),
    type:DS.attr('string'),
  title: DS.attr('string'),
    desc: DS.attr('string'),
    diff_level: DS.attr('string'),
  answer: DS.attr('boolean')
});

Equizz.Question.FIXTURES = [
 {
    qid: '1',
    category: 'Track',
    type:'True & False',
  title: 'Get 100 in the quizz is the most disgraced act in simulator lab.',
    desc: 'think clearly, you should know the answer without use your brain...',
    diff_level: 'Hard',
  answer: false
 },
 {
    qid: '2',
    category: 'Common',
    type:'True & False',
  title: 'You are allowed to eat in simulator lab.',
    desc: 'Like what? Halal?',
    diff_level: 'Medium',
  answer: false
 },
 {
    qid: '3',
    category: 'BS',
    type:'True & False',
  title: 'fsafasf asf asjfkl; as fkasl; faf a;sf sf asfl; sjlfjs a; fsl fas;f dsaf aslfj asl;fj a;fj alfj slafj a?',
    desc: 'Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?Like what? Halal?',
    diff_level: 'Easy',
  answer: true
 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring your route correctly. For the questions route, you need to create Equizz.QuestionsRoute, not Equizz.EquizzRoute.

To be able to use {{#each}} in your template, the controller has to be an ArrayController. If the corresponding route is returning an array from the model hook, the auto generated controller should be just this. Since you don't have a QuestionsRoute returning an array model, Ember is generating the default, non-array-ish controller.

You should read the [docs regarding routes](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/), explains the whole route/controller/view naming scheme.

Comment: But how could TodoMVC able to do it without a controlller?

Comment: btw, now I got a error of Error while loading route: 
Error
message: "the id property must be defined as a number or string for fixture {qid: 1, category: Track, type: True & False, title: Get 100 in the quizz is the most disgraced act in simulator lab., desc: think clearly, you should know the answer without use your brain..., diff_level: Hard, answer: false}"
stack: (...)

Comment: Ember generates controllers for routes if one is not provided. If the model for a route is an array, the route has to provide an array from the model hook.

In the Todo example, the route is providing an array model, so Ember knows to generate an ArrayController for that route.

Also, the fixtures needs an 'id' property, yours is defined as 'qid'.

Answer (score 0):

Ember.js relies on it's own set of [naming conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/). The route 'question' has a Ember.Route named QuestionRoute. Thus

Equizz.EquizzRoute => Equizz.QuestionRoute.

Ember fixtures also have there own ["naming" conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/#toc_naming-conventions) and are required to have a unique id. Thus

```
qid => id
```

This also implies that ember has it's own concept of ids associated to models, and thus your model's custom id is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue following along with another tutorial.

Like @Dawson mentioned, the Fixture Adapter follows different rules than the REST adapter. Here is the relevant text from the [link](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-fixture-adapter/#toc_naming-conventions) @Dawson provided:

> NAMING CONVENTIONS
>
> Unlike the REST Adapter, the Fixture Adapter does not make any
>   assumptions about the naming conventions of your model. As you saw in
>   the example above, if you declare the attribute as firstName during
>   DS.Model.extend, you use firstName to represent the same field in your
>   fixture data.
>
> **Importantly, you should make sure that each record in your fixture
>   data has a uniquely identifiable field. By default, Ember Data assumes
>   this key is called id. Should you not provide an id field in your
>   fixtures, or not override the primary key, the Fixture Adapter will
>   throw an error.**

To work around this:

Assuming my model is called `Item` (`item.js`)

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var Item = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    description:  DS.attr('string'),
    price:  DS.attr('number'),
    qty: DS.attr('number'),
    images: DS.attr('string'), 
    sold: DS.attr('boolean'),
});
```

I built my Fixture data in another object:

```
//Fixtures require an ID field not supplied by the DS.model
//write the fixtures to an object then append IDs in a loop later
var f = [
        {
            title: "Nesting Tables",
            description: "Set of 3 matching nesting tables in a cherry finish",
            price: "25",
            qty: 1,
            images: '"DSC_0552.JPG"', 
            sold: false
        },
        {
            title: "Brown Leather Storage Ottomans",
            description: "Nicely finished with nail-head rivets.",
            price: "45",
            qty: 2,
            images: '"DSC_0554.JPG","DSC_0556.JPG"', 
            sold: false 
        },
        {
            title: "Black 3 shelf bookcase",
            description: "Handsome black wood bookcase with 3 shelves",
            price: "40",
            qty: 1,
            images: '"DSC_0559.JPG","DSC_0557.JPG"', 
            sold: false 
        }
];
```

Then used a loop to add IDs to each element:

```
// here is our loop to add IDs to the fixtures 
var c = f.length; 
for (var i=0; i<c;i++)
{
   f[i].id = i; 
}
```

Then assigned the completed `f` Object to the `FIXTURES` object in the model:

```
Item.reopenClass({
    FIXTURES: f
});
```

This way, the Fixtures look like my final REST data, but I have the necessary pieces in place to use the FixtureAdapter.